# Z3 Managed Exception : Java API while trying to use propagate-ineqs tactic

Tags: exception, z3, smt, java

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)

(assert (exists ((a0 Int) (b0 Int) (c0 Int))
 (and (<= a 3)
      (>= a 0)
      (<= b 3)
      (>= b 0)
      (<= c 3)
      (>= c 0)
      (= 3 (+ a b c))
      (> a 1)
      (= a0 a)
      (= b0 b)
      (= c0 c)
      (= a0 2)
      (= b0 0)
      (= c0 1))))
(apply  (then qe ctx-solver-simplify propagate-ineqs))
```

I am trying to generate this code using the provided Java-API for the **Z3 Solver**. However, this ends up throwing the following Exception:

**Z3 Managed Exception**: propagate-ineqs does not support unsat core production

```
 Goal g = ctx.mkGoal(true, true, false);
 g.add((BoolExpr) exp);
 Tactic qe = ctx.mkTactic("qe");
 Tactic simpify = ctx.mkTactic("simplify");
 Tactic ctxSimpify = ctx.mkTactic("ctx-simplify");
 Tactic ctxSolverSimplify = ctx.mkTactic("ctx-solver-simplify");
 Tactic propagateIneqs = ctx.mkTactic("propagate-ineqs");
 Tactic then = ctx.then(qe, simpify, ctxSimpify, ctxSolverSimplify,
            propagateIneqs);
 ApplyResult ar = then.apply(g);
 BoolExpr result = ctx.mkAnd(ar.getSubgoals()[0].getFormulas());
```

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong and how can I use the tactic *propagate-ineqs* in Java-API. So that, I can get answers with trivial inequalities are simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
 Goal g = ctx.mkGoal(true, true, false);
```

asks for unsat core extraction to be enabled (the second `true`) for the goal `g`, but the `propagate-ineqs` tactic does not support that feature, so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly turning off the unsat core feature during the construction of your Context ctx. You can pass a Map with options and their values. The option for unsat cores is "unsat_core" and can be set to "true" or "false".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried as you suggested. However, the exception is still thrown.  I assume this what you meant `HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<String, String>();
    cfg.put("unsat_core", "false");
    Context ctx = new Context(cfg);`